# Construct NSPredicate for NSArray of ids

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have created entity called Student in which we are storing student details.

[image]

I am trying to construct predicate to fetch few student details based on there ID's.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sid IN %@",@[@"1",@"2",@"3"]]];
```

Always getting error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "Sid IN (
    1,
    2,
    3
)"'
```

Comment: is `Sid` is type of `NSNumber`?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr its NSString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not (and in almost all cases there is no need to) mix `stringWithFormat:` and 
`predicateWithFormat:`. In this case a simple

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Sid IN %@", @[@"1",@"2",@"3"]]
```

should do.